# not able to ng serve after updated from angular version 7 to version 8, giving error after 95% not a directory

Tags: angular

This is my angular version and node version

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.26
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, elements
... forms, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.803.26
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.803.26
@angular-devkit/core                       8.3.26
@angular-devkit/schematics                 8.3.26
@angular/cli                               8.3.26
@ngtools/webpack                           8.3.26
@nguniversal/express-engine                7.1.1
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   0.0.0
@schematics/angular                        8.3.26
@schematics/update                         0.803.26
rxjs                                       6.5.5
typescript                                 3.5.3
webpack
```

and this is my error

```
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:5500/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html
95% emitting index-html-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: not a directory
    at MemoryFileSystem.mkdirpSync (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\memory-fs\lib\MemoryFileSystem.js:144:10)
    at MemoryFileSystem.(anonymous function) [as mkdirp] (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\memory-fs\lib\MemoryFileSystem.js:279:34)     
    at asyncLib.forEachLimit (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:461:29)
    at objectIteratorWithKey (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3509:9)
    at done (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3527:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at outputFileSystem.writeFile.err (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:437:33)
    at MemoryFileSystem.writeFile (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\memory-fs\lib\MemoryFileSystem.js:328:9)
    at writeOut (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:424:30)
    at asyncLib.forEachLimit (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:466:7)
    at objectIteratorWithKey (C:\projects\thesocialcomment\frontend\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3509:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
enter code here
enter code here
```

can any one tell me why i am having this error. I got this error after i update my angular version from 7 to 8 using

```
ng update
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the problem

**I am using glob input like this**

```
"assets": [
              ...
              {
                "glob": "./",
                "input": "node_modules/some/path",
                "output": "assets/"
              }
            ],
```

**after changing this to this**

```
"assets": [
              ...
              {
                "glob": "some_filename.ext",
                "input": "node_modules/file_directory",
                "output": "assets/"
              }
            ],
```

then it compile successfully, looks like the like glob is finding the file in wrong directory which is not even a directory causing this error

now every thing works fine.